# Google Fit - Creating and sending data to a data Source for step counter using Recording API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

So I'm developing a fitness application that tracks users steps and decided to go with Google Fit APIs as their data collection uses subscriptions and promises highly optimised battery usage. I am using Recording API to collect user data. However, I cannot figure out a way to create a unique dataSource that collects user com.google.step_count.delta data type. This is important as this will be a unique derived source that contains user steps along with a few manipulations to steps done by the application in the later phase of processing.
I thought subscribing to a new type of data Source using Recording Api would intelligently create a required data source if not existing but that does not seem to be the case. 
Here is my subscription code for Recording API:

```
public static DataSource createDataSource(){
    return new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("com.sharesmile.share.core")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setDevice(Device.getLocalDevice(getContext()))
            .setName("ImpactSteps")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build();
}

private void createRecordingSubscription() {
    String TAG = "Data Source";
    Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PASSIVE, "Creating a recording subscription");

    Logger.d(TAG, "\nName: " + dataSource.getName()
            + "\nPkg name: " + dataSource.getAppPackageName()
            + "\nStream Identifier: " + dataSource.getStreamIdentifier()
            + "\nData Type: " + dataSource.getDataType()
            + "\nDevice: " + dataSource.getDevice()
            + "\nType: " + dataSource.getType());
    DataSource dataSource = Utils.createDataSource();
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(
            GoogleApiHelper.getInstance().getGoogleApiClient(),
            dataSource);
    Status status = pendingResult.await(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Logger.d(Constants.TAG_PASSIVE, "Recording subscription created successfully. \nSuccess Code: "+status.getStatusCode());
        fetchFitnessData();
    } else {
        GoogleAnalyticsEvent.getInstance().sendUserActionEvent(GAEvents.ON_GOOGLE_FIT_DATA_RECEIVE_FAILURE, "Recording Subscription");
        Logger.e(Constants.TAG_PASSIVE, "Unable to create recording subscription");
    }
}
```

> The result of this subscription is Success. However the returned status code is -5000 i.e according to FitnessStatusCode **SUCCESS_NO_DATA_SOURCES**

If I later query all available dataSource for dataType Steps using Sensor API using the below code:

```
final DataSourcesRequest dataSourcesRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .build();

    String TAG = "Data Source";

    PendingResult<DataSourcesResult> pendingResult1 = Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(
            GoogleApiHelper.getInstance().getGoogleApiClient(), dataSourcesRequest);
    DataSourcesResult result = pendingResult1.await();
    for(DataSource dataSource : result.getDataSources()){
        Logger.d(TAG, "\nName: " + dataSource.getName()
        + "\nPkg name: " + dataSource.getAppPackageName()
        + "\nStream Identifier: " + dataSource.getStreamIdentifier()
        + "\nData Type: " + dataSource.getDataType()
        + "\nDevice: " + dataSource.getDevice()
        + "\nType: " + dataSource.getType()
        + "\nToken: " + SharedPrefsManager.getInstance().getString(Constants.PREF_LOGIN_TOKEN));
    }
```

As expected from the Status Code, the data source is not found. 
Using History API to read step data also returns a null dataSet.
Please help me creating a data Source and successfully using Recording API to record user steps on Google Fit Store.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. do let me know if you find the solution to this.